# Slip up to display FetchedData from Api to card using map() in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am a learner and tryiyng to make website using frontend react.js and backend node.js.I have created  Api  using node.js and want to display the data in card.Though data fetched but image doesn't show and all data(all image,name,price) are showed in one card.how to solve it?

---

<Slider {...settings}>
{

```
    products.map((popularObject, i) => (
      <li key={popularObject._id}>
        <div className="card-wrapper">

          <ul className="product">
            <div className="card">
              <Link to={'/product/' + popularObject._id}>
                <img className="card-image" src={
                  (typeof (popularObject.popular) == 'object') ?
                    <div>
                      {
                        popularObject.popular.map((subpopularObject, index) => {
                          <div key={index}>
                            {subpopularObject.imageUrl}
                          </div>
                        }
                        )
                      }
                    </div>
                    :
                    null
                } alt="popular" />
              </Link>

              <div className="details">
                <div className="job-title">
                  <h4><p className="tag">Radhunir Rannaghor</p><Link to={'/product/' + popularObject._id}>
                    {
                      (typeof (popularObject.popular) == 'object') ?
                        <div>
                          {
                            popularObject.popular.map((subpopularobj,index) =>

                              <div key={index}>{subpopularobj.name}</div>
                            )
                          }
                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                    }

                  </Link><span className="job-title"></span> </h4>
                </div>
                <div className="job-title-price"> <h4> ${popularObject.popular[i].price}</h4></div>

              </div>

            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

    ))}
</Slider>
```

```js
   
// here is data.js

  {
    products: [
      {
        popular: [
          {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'Nasi Goreng',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/3.jpg',
            rating: '5.0',
            deliveryTime: '45 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Extra special'
          },
          {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'Rendang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/7.jpg',
            rating: '4.9',
            deliveryTime: '35 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '250',
            note: 'Special'
          },
          {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'Nasi Padang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/16.jpg',
            rating: '4.5',
            deliveryTime: '55 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Delivery charges 50 extra',
            price: '199',
            note: 'Chilly'
          },
          {
            _id: '7',
            name: 'Pece',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/13.jpg',
            rating: '4.0',
            deliveryTime: '75 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Special, Spicy'
          },
          {
            _id: '4',
            name: 'Indomie',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/13.jpg',
            rating: '3.8',
            deliveryTime: '25 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Special, Spicy'
          }
        ],
        recommended: [
          {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'Rendang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/7.jpg',
            rating: '4.9',
            deliveryTime: '35 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '250',
            note: 'Special'
          },
          {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'Nasi Goreng',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/3.jpg',
            rating: '5.0',
            deliveryTime: '45 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Extra special'
          },
          {
            _id: '7',
            name: 'Pece',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/13.jpg',
            rating: '4.0',
            deliveryTime: '75 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Special, Spicy'
          }
        ],
        allmenu: [
          {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'Nasi Goreng',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/3.jpg',
            rating: '5.0',
            deliveryTime: '45 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Extra special'
          },
          {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'Rendang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/4.jpg',
            rating: '4.9',
            deliveryTime: '35 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '250',
            note: 'Special'
          },
          {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'Nasi Padang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/6.jpg',
            rating: '4.5',
            deliveryTime: '55 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Delivery charges 50 extra',
            price: '199',
            note: 'Chilly'
          },
          {
            _id: '4',
            name: 'Indomie',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/12.jpg',
            rating: '3.8',
            deliveryTime: '25 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Special, Spicy'
          },
          {
            _id: '5',
            name: 'Rendang',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/6.jpg',
            rating: '4.9',
            deliveryTime: '35 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '250',
            note: 'Special'
          },
          {
            _id: '6',
            name: "Nasi Goreng",
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/7.jpg',
            rating: '5.0',
            deliveryTime: '45 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '250',
            note: ''
          },
          {
            _id: '7',
            name: 'Pece',
            imageUrl: 'imagestest/1.jpg',
            rating: '4.0',
            deliveryTime: '75 mins',
            deliveryCharges: 'Free Delivery',
            price: '150',
            note: 'Special, Spicy'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
```

///output

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add a working sample using codesandbox l?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to display 1 card per popular product.

So it means that the first `map` should be on `products.popular` instead of simply `products`:

```
<Slider {...settings}> {

    products.popular.map((popularObject, i) => (
      <li key={popularObject._id}>
      // …
      </li>
    ))

}
</Slider>
```

By doing this change, it implied that all the internal `map` you're using for each of the different part of the card does not exist anymore, as you already have `popularObject` in scope with every value needed.